# Do you get charged for a security group in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I recently had an EC2 instance that I terminated, I've deleted everything except for the Default Security Group which I am not allowed to delete. Note: I've deleted all the Inbound Rules and Outbound Rules. My bill still reflects EC2 charges which are by the hour. Do I need to worry about deleting this security group?

Comment: You are not being charged for a security group.  Do you perhaps have a unused Elastic IP address or EBS volume?

Comment: It shows 0 Elastic IP and 0 Load Balances.  The service was just terminated yesterday.

Comment: What about EBS volumes?

Comment: 0 instances of EBS

Comment: You can drill down and check the itemized charges.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no charge applicable to Security Groups in Amazon EC2 / Amazon VPC.

You can drill-down into your billing charges via the **Billing Dashboard**. Just click **Bill Details**, expand the **Elastic Compute Cloud** section and a breakdown of charges will be displayed:

[image: EC2 billing detail]

You should then be able to see the origin of your charges.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS documentation says "f you terminate an underlying Amazon EC2 instance, the service that started it might interpret the termination as a failure and restart the instance."
So you could check on this,also check if you are using any services ,cost will be incurred if anything is launched using the services.

Are you using a free tier account?
The cost incurred is different if your free tier period is completed just a heads up.